# Prove that there exist infinite many integers $m$ such that $\gcd\left(\binom{m}{k},l\right)=1$

Tags: number-theory

Let $k,l$ be two given integers. Prove that there exist infinite many integers $m(\ge k)$ such that $$\gcd\left(\binom{m}{k},l\right)=1$$

The number-theory book hint use [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem),I can't How to do it, Thank you graciously!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each prime $p\mid l$ let $a_p$ the multiplicity of $p$ in $k!$. For $n>\max\{a_p:p\mid l\}$, take $m=l^n+k$.

Then the multiplicity of $p$ in $(l^n+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(l^n+k)$ is the same as in $k!$. Indeed, if we call $m_p(r)$ the multiplicity of $p$ in $r$, we have, for each $1\le j\le k$,
$$m_p(l^n+j)=\min\{m_p(l^n),m_p(j)\}=m_p(j)$$
since $m_p(j)\le a_p< n\le n\cdot m_p(l)$.

So $\binom{l^n+k}k$ is not a multiple of $p$.

Comment: why  you take $m=l^n+k$ can you explain How to find this example?,PS,you  don't use Lucas?

Comment: The idea of taking $l^n+k$ comes from taking a number that has great multiplicities for the primes that divide $l$, to make sure that the next $k$ numbers have not. So, $l^n$, for big $n$ has big multiplicities for such primes, so $l^n+1, l^n+2,\ldots, l^n+k$ have the same multiplicities as $1,2,\ldots, k$.

Comment: Not sure, but I think that my solution gives less examples than Fischer's and with greater numbers. For example, for $k=4$, $l=6$, the least example for my solution would be $\binom{1300}4$.

Comment: sorry,you and his solution don't understand until now

Comment: I could help if you specify which step(s) you don't understand.

Comment: can you use Lucas to explain $p\nmid \binom{l^n+k}{k}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25997/discussion-between-ajotatxe-and-abandon).